# I can't unmarshal basic string from akka http stream

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http, play-json

I am trying to consume a stream of json objects in akka-http. ( akka http version  "10.0.9", akka-http-play-json version 1.10.1)

I follow examples on web but, for String I am getting:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromByteStringUnmarshaller[String]
```

and for my user defined Foo case class (for which I provided the json protocol):

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromByteStringUnmarshaller[server.Foo]
```

This is the code that is simplified. I provide a `EntityStreamingSupport.json()` and for the Foo object a Json Format. I don't think I need one for String. If I don't put the `asSourceOf` and read a simple String object or a Foo case class object the code works. What am I missing?

```
package server

import akka.http.scaladsl.common.EntityStreamingSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{ Directives, Route }
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpplayjson.PlayJsonSupport._
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Foo(bar: String)

class StreamingMarketDataUpload extends Directives {
  implicit val jsonStreamingSupport = EntityStreamingSupport.json()
  implicit val jsonFooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
  lazy val routes: Route =
    path("upload1") {
      post {
        entity(as[String]) { input =>
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        }
      }
    } ~ path("upload2") { 
      post {
        // Compile error here
        entity(asSourceOf[String]) { marks =>
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        }
      }
    } ~ path("upload3") {
      post {
        entity(as[Foo]) { input =>
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        }
      }
    } ~ path("upload4") {
      post {
        // Compile error here
        entity(asSourceOf[Foo]) { marks =>
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`asSourceOf[T]` tries to consume the incoming data as a `Source[T, _]`. As its [method signature](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.9/akka/http/scaladsl/server/Directives.html#asSourceOf[T](support:akka.http.scaladsl.common.EntityStreamingSupport)(implicitum:akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromByteStringUnmarshaller[T]):FramedEntityStreamingDirectives.this.RequestToSourceUnmarshaller[T]) indicates, `asSourceOf[T]` takes an implicit `FromByteStringUnmarshaller[T]` parameter. The [`de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpplayjson.PlayJsonSupport`](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/blob/v1.19.0/akka-http-play-json/src/main/scala/de/heikoseeberger/akkahttpplayjson/PlayJsonSupport.scala) utility doesn't provide an implementation of this unmarshaller (as of version 1.19.0), but it does provide the unmarshallers necessary for consuming a simple `String` or `Foo`. This is why your code works when it's not using `asSourceOf`.

The examples in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html) use [`SprayJsonSupport`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.9/akka-http-marshallers-scala/akka-http-spray-json/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/marshallers/sprayjson/SprayJsonSupport.scala), which is shipped as part of Akka HTTP. If you don't want to use `SprayJsonSupport`, you'll have to implement a `FromByteStringUnmarshaller` to use `asSourceOf`: the linked source code can give you an idea of how to do this.

Comment: I thought there might be some implicits that I needed to import to create the `FromByteStringUnmarshaller`. Got it.